# difference between import-csv and convert-csv in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have read this article https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/06/24/import-csv-cleanup.aspx I still don't get the difference between `Import-Csv` and `ConvertFrom-Csv` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty simple.

**Import-CSV** is used to get external data from a CSV file stored on a hard drive, or other media. Let's say you have a file with the following data saved on your drive at C:\Temp\Users.csv:

```
FirstName,LastName,Alias
Bob,Smith,BSmith
Joe,Anderson,JAnde
Rebecca,Johnson,RJohn
```

You can do the following to get that information into PowerShell:

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Temp\Users.csv
```

**ConvertFrom-CSV** is used when you have the CSV data already in PowerShell as an array of strings. Such as:

```
$CSVStrings = @("FirstName,LastName,Alias", "Bob,Smith,BSmith", "Joe,Anderson,JAnde", "Rebecca,Johnson,RJohn")
$Users = $CSVStrings | ConvertFrom-CSV
```

Either way, you would have an array of objects. Each object would have 3 properties. This can be seen as such:

```
$Users | Format-List

FirstName : Bob
LastName  : Smith
Alias     : BSmith

FirstName : Joe
LastName  : Anderson
Alias     : JAnde

FirstName : Rebecca
LastName  : Johnson
Alias     : RJohn
```

Comment: Another difference is that Import-CSV can handle newlines inside quoted strings, whereas ConvertFrom-CSV struggles with them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218416/powershell-parsing-pipeline-csv-data-with-newlines-using-convertfrom-csv

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference is that the CSV side of `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` are files, and the CSV side of `ConvertTo-Csv` and `ConvertFrom-Csv` are objects within the script.