# PowerShell: list CSV file rows where at least one value between the 3rd and last column is equal to "0" or "1"

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, filtering, import-csv

In my PowerShell script, I'm working with a CSV file that looks like this (with a number of rows and columns that can vary, but there will always be at least the headers and the first 2 columns):

```
OS;IP;user0;user1;user3
Windows;10.0.0.1;;;
Linux;hostname2;0;;1
Linux;10.0.0.3;;0;0
Linux;hostname4;;;
Windows;hostname5;1;1;1
```

I basically list servers in the first column and users in the first row (CSV header). This represents a user "access granting" matrix to servers (1 for "give access", 0 for "remove access", and void for "don't change").

I'm looking for a way to extract only the rows that include a value equal to "1" or "0" between (and including) the 3rd and last column. (= to eventually get the list of servers where access rights should be changed)

So taking the above example, I only want the following lines returned:

```
Linux;hostname2;0;;1
Linux;10.0.0.3;;0;0
Windows;hostname5;1;1;1
```

Any hints to make this possible? Or the opposite (getting the ones without any 0 or 1)?
 Even if it means using "Get-Content" instead of "Import-CSV". I don't care about the 1st (headers) row; I know how to exclude that.

Thank you!

***--- Final solution, thanks to @Tomalak's answer:***

```
$AccessMatrix = Import-CSV $CSVfile -delimiter ';'
$columns = $AccessMatrix | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -Skip 2 -ExpandProperty Name
$AccessMatrix = $AccessMatrix | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $_
    foreach ($col in $columns) {
        if ($row.$col.trim() -eq "1" -OR $row.$col.trim() -eq "0") {
            $row         # this pushes the $row onto the pipeline
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `Get-Member` to select the names of all columns after the first two.

Then, using `ForEach-Object`, we can output only those rows that have a value in any of those columns.

```
$data = ConvertFrom-Csv "OS;IP;user0;user1;user3
Windows;10.0.0.1;;;
Linux;hostname2;0;;1
Linux;10.0.0.3;;0;0
Linux;hostname4;;;
Windows;hostname5;1;1;1" -Delimiter ";"

$columns = $data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -Skip 2 -ExpandProperty Name

$data | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $_
    foreach ($col in $columns) {
        if ($row.$col -ne "") {
            $row         # this pushes the $row onto the pipeline
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The `break` statement stops the execution of the inner `foreach` loop because there is no point in further checking as soon as the first column with any value is found.

This is equivalent to the above, if you prefer `Where-Object`:

```
$data | Where-Object {
    $row = $_
    foreach ($col in $columns) {
        if ($row.$col -ne "") {
            return $true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, I got confused with the "ConvertFrom-Csv", but I eventually found how to adapt this into my script. That works great!

Comment: "Convert from CSV (into a PowerShell data structure)" is what it means.

Comment: Yeah, actually in my case I needed to use Import-CSV (since my data comes from a file). Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770843/difference-between-import-csv-and-convert-csv-in-powershell

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I only used it because I already had a string and just needed to convert it. `Import-CSV $file` is basically equivalent to `Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Comment: Hey, I just came across a bug using my script because the Get-Member here lists the headers in alphabetical order (so usernames that are before "OS" or "Host" in alphabetical order get in front of them and then skipped in the piped Select-Object statement, while the "OS" and "Host" may appear in the output). // I worked around it by removing the Skip altogether (since a single '1' or '0' will never appear in the first two columns), but I was wondering is there is a way for "Get-Member" to output in the same order as the CSV data.

Comment: How about `$data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Where {"IP","OS" -notcontains $_.Name} | Select -ExpandProperty Name`?